# How to capture frame from toll gate camera video only when a vehicle is at a halt, using Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I've a scenario where only trucks will pass a toll gate of which I want to capture the number plate only when the truck has halted (to get a good quality image to run OCR on). The OCR solution is built but capturing a frame every time a truck comes to a halt seems to be tricky to me.

Can you help me with the approach or a similar working code to achieve the same using Python 3.6+ and OpenCV. I'm not willing to run any explicit model to detect motion or something, just a simple background subtraction would do, in order to avoid overhead time.

Sample image frame from the video: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7knU.jpg).

Here is the code I'm currently working on, it checks if the background subtraction between two respective frames is more than 10% threshold, then it captures the frame. But, I've to do just the opposite, i.e, if background subtraction is zero, then capture the frame, more logic needs to be added here, like, after capturing a frame, we've to skip all following static frames which are true positive until the the next truck arrives and comes to a halt.

The code:

```
x_0 = 720
x_1 = 870
y_0 = 190
y_1 = 360
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r"C:\\Users\\aa\\file.asf")

i=0

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (21, 21), 0)
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
        fgmask_crop= fgmask[y_0:y_1, x_0:x_1]
        frame_crop = frame[y_0:y_1, x_0:x_1]
        #out_video.write(frame_crop)
        cv2.imshow("crop", fgmask_crop)
        fg = cv2.copyTo(frame,fgmask)
        bg=cv2.copyTo(frame,cv2.bitwise_not(fgmask))
        pixels = cv2.countNonZero(fgmask_crop)
        image_area = frame_crop.shape[0] * frame_crop.shape[1]
        area_ratio = (pixels / image_area) * 100
        if area_ratio>10:
            i=i+1
            print(i)
            target= 'C:\\Users\\aa\\op'
            fileName = ("res%d.png" % (i))
            path_nm = os.path.join(target, fileName)
            cv2.imwrite(path_nm,frame_crop)
        key = cv2.waitKey(25)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#out.release()
cap.release()
```

Any help shall be highly acknowledged.

Comment: Hi - please edit a [mre] of your latest attempt to solve your problem into your question.

Comment: Just thinking aloud and happy to be corrected... as these are heavy trucks, they are unlikely to be accelerating or decelerating very fast, so they'll be unlikely to be doing more than 1-5mph at any point in your frame. Furthermore, your camera is at 45 or so degrees across their track so the speed component is reduced anyway. So, I suspect your video is using a shutter speed of less than 1/30 second, so I imagine the number plate should be pretty much frozen in all frames whether the truck is stopped or not. As I said, I'm happy to be corrected.

Comment: @Barny, I'll update the question with the code i'm using currently, though it is for the opposite requirement, it only captures frames when there is background difference between frames.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, most of your assumptions are bang on, but we do not want to unnecessarily process every frame, hence, not passing each frame to the downstream OCR job. Now, since we're doing that, the code needs to intelligently know when we get the next truck's number plate with least possible load on the processors (minimum processing time). The 'halt' requirement is just to ensure we get the best quality as some cameras have lower resolution and we want a generic solution which can be implemented on all feeds.

Comment: Any help? I've updated the question.